# React-Native Changing inputText background for a second

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a React Native app and I have an issue. I want to make inputText background green for just a second when user answers correctly. I do not use button so if user have correct answer, the inputText will be empty (''). I am using useState for this. If the text is the correct answer, setWord('') is triggered.

`const [word, setWord] = useState('');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the usual background-color is white and the correct background-color will be green.

Add a background color state like this:

```
const [textinputBackgroundColor, setTextinputBackgroundColor] = useState('white');
```

Now, wherever you check the correctness of the text - whenever the text is correct you can change the background color like this:

```
setTextinputBackgroundColor('green');
setTimeout(() => setTextinputBackgroundColor('white'), 1000);
```

The timeout will revert the white background color after 1 second.